# git grep: search pattern: x[any thing, any size]y?

Tags: git, grep

i'm trying to look in a huge repo the following pattern and i can figure out how:
I want to look for any line that contain `BASE` and then `D45`
expected results:

```
ABASE_EX        0xD4555555
BASE_AD         84500
etc..
```

Comment: How about `git grep BASE.*D45`?

Comment: Please consider reading [this book](http://regex.info/book.html) which is a *de-facto standard* on the subject.